# PowerShell starts prepending file paths with Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I am experiencing the following behavior in PowerShell that I cannot explain and find cumbersome.

I am working in an arbitrary directory and the path of the directory is shown in the prompt:

```
PS C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp>
```

Also, `get-location` reports the "correct" path:

```
PS C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp> get-location

Path
----
C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp
```

I then type `mkdir xyz | cd` in order to create a directory and change the working directory into this new directory:

```
PS C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp> mkdir xyz | cd
```

All of a sudden, the path in the prompt is prefixed with `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::`:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp\xyz>
```

This change is also reflected with `get-location`:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp\xyz> get-location

Path
----
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\Rene\AppData\Local\Temp\xyz
```

What is going on here and how can I turn that prefix off?

Comment: That's because of how pipeline binding of file system items work. What you're seeing is "the real path" as seen by PowerShell. You can avoid this by doing `mkdir xyz |cd -Path {$_.FullName}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reverse order:

> ## How can I turn that prefix off?

Easy, use *explicit* pipeline binding!

```
mkdir xyz |cd -Path {$_.FullName}
```

---

> ## What is going on here?

Great question! What you see here is a side-effect of how the provider cmdlets (`Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Item`, `Set-Location` etc.) implements ***pipeline binding***.

When you call `New-Item` (which is what `mkdir` does) against the `FileSystem` provider, it returns an object (corresponding to the newly created file or directory) that has a bunch of hidden properties that PowerShell uses to keep track of items across providers - these can be discovered with `Get-Member -Force`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Item .|Get-Member PS* -MemberType NoteProperty -Force


   TypeName: System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Name          MemberType   Definition
----          ----------   ----------
PSChildName   NoteProperty string PSChildName=C:\
PSDrive       NoteProperty PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C
PSIsContainer NoteProperty bool PSIsContainer=True
PSParentPath  NoteProperty string PSParentPath=
PSPath        NoteProperty string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\
PSProvider    NoteProperty ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
```

When you construct a pipeline statement with a provider cmdlet (such as `Set-Location`/`cd` for example) downstream, it uses the provider-qualified `PSPath` value to figure bind the input object.

This can be observed with `Trace-Command`:

```
PS C:\> Trace-Command -Expression {Get-Item .|Set-Location} -Name ParameterBinding,MemberResolution -PSHost
```

Which results in (I've removed the details for `Get-Item` for brevity):

```
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Set-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Set-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Set-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Path] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\\] to parameter [Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [C:\\] to param [Path] SKIPPED
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Path] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :     Lookup
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         "Path" NOT present in type table.
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         Adapted member: not found.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [StackName] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :     Lookup
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         "StackName" NOT present in type table.
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         Adapted member: not found.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [LiteralPath] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :     Lookup
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         "LiteralPath" NOT present in type table.
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         Adapted member: not found.
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :     Lookup
DEBUG: MemberResolution Information: 0 :         Found PSObject instance member: PSPath.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\] to parameter [LiteralPath]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\] to param [LiteralPath] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Set-Location]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
```

As you can see, PowerShell foregoes binding `C:\` to `Set-Location`s `-Path` parameter, as somehow binding the `PSPath` property value to `-LiteralPath` is more appropriate?!

The reason for that is that the `-LiteralPath` parameter is aliased to `PSPath`, as can be seen by digging a bit with `Get-Command`:

```bsh
PS C:\> (Get-Command Set-Location).Parameters['LiteralPath'] |Select Aliases

Aliases
-------
{PSPath}
```

The real reason *why* pipeline bindings for provider cmdlets is implemented this way, is twofold:

1. Binding a "provider-native" string representation directly to `Path` might have unintended consequences related to *globbing*

   - `Get-Item -Path 'a[bcd]'` and `Get-Item -LiteralPath 'a[bcd]'` are two *wildly different* queries for example
2. Binding on the provider-qualified `PSPath` value means that we can switch location to a different provider without losing automatic binding:

   - ie. `PS Cert:\> $aFile |Get-Content` *just works*

Comment: Especially your last example (`PS Cert:\> $aFile |Get-Content`) explains the behavior. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon what Mathias posted you can use a very simple filter to save some typing and accomplish the same thing. Put this in a script and run it, run it directly, or drop it in your profile:

```
filter slp(){
    Set-Location -Path $_.FullName
}
```

You can then use:

```
mkdir | slp
```

Which will work identically to:

```
mkdir | sl
```

You can of course make the filter anything you want. "cdp" instead of "slp" for example.